# (Rugby) stadium crowds [request]

Tags: request, recording, crowd

I'm doing an installation where I need to simulate the sound of a stadium from the player's perspective. It needs to sound huge and really exciting! I already have some sounds that work from various jobs and recording missions I've had, but I need a ton more!

**sounds & perspectives** (I can obviously edit and process these sounds)

- From inside changing room (maybe stomping, distant chanting, players walking)
- From almost out, but still inside (screaming, chanting, stomping, crowd building up)
- From the rugby pitch, with swells of crowd going wild.

I'm trying to get access to a game over the weekend, but the schedule is super tight (I have three days to do it all, including recording, design and programming).

Does anyone have some sounds they don't mind letting me use? We can do a swop. Or does anyone know what library (high quality pref) has some of these? It doesn't have to be rugby only, I can mix and match to make it work.

Thanks so much for any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Hey,

I'm going to a footbal game tonight and was planning on recording some crowd chanting/singing etc. Might only be able record from the 'terrace perspective', but my seat is on the first row... might be something in there for you?

The games between FC Basel and FC Zürich get quite heated, with a lot of singing, screaming, flares being fired, PA announcements reprimanding flare-firers and the like.

Will put it on dropbox when I get home tonight..

Your installation sounds really interesting! Who/what is it for?

Kurt

Comment: if you need any more info/pass me on any info i'm @pushformono on twitter and my email is contact AT kurthuman.com 

Comment: Thanks so much Kurt! That's awesome of you! It's for BMW, but I can't say more at this stage. My library is your if you need it. One of the main sounds is the moment when a key player walks onto the pitch, when the crowd goes coocoo. 

Answer (score 1):

I also have some football game recordings.  FC dallas vs some other random team.  Vuvzelas, drumming, cheers, fireworks, idling, etc.

ping me and I'll hook you up.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much Rene :-) I'll send you an email in a bit. 

Answer (score 0):

Considering the recent "Osama Death Crowd Field Recordings" conversation... if you actually found some of them then bits of those might be useful if they're nondescript enough. Even ripping some of the audio from youtube using "Audio Hijack" and drowning it in chorus and/or reverb might prove useful for at least a bit of massive crowd/chorusing backfill noise, if not useful for more.

See that? I'm practically eating my own words from that last thread just a little more than a week later. lol

Comment: *especially considering you'll likely have to run a lot of low pass filters for psychological and dynamic effect to mute out most of it until the crowd goes "CooCoo for BMW Puffs".